# Javascript code not executing within app.component.html

Tags: javascript, angular

In my `app.component.html` I have delcared this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log('testing console')
</script>
```

When I load `app.component.html` the javascript is not executed as the message 'testing console' is not printed to the browser console.

I'm using the Angular version:

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.0
Node: 14.15.5
OS: darwin x64

Angular: 11.2.0
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1102.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1102.0
@angular-devkit/core            11.2.0
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.0
@schematics/angular             11.2.0
@schematics/update              0.1102.0
rxjs                            6.6.3
typescript                      4.1.5
```

I realise executing javascript code within app.component.html could be bad practice. How/can javascript code be executed within an Angular page ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, it's possible but severely not recommended to run JS that way in an Angular app.  You could use the ngOnInit() function in your `app.component.ts` file like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("testing console");
  }

}
```

Comment: As an addition: depending on your use case on when you want to execute the code, you can also use other Lifecycle hook interfaces. [Check this documentation for that](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

You could also put it in the constructor, but I'm not sure whether that's recommended or not.